# Is there a way to write two lists to a .csv two to separate columns in Apple Script?

Tags: shell, scripting, applescript

Looking to automate writing the filesizes of files/folders immediately beneath a directory to a .csv

du -sh is the closes to what I'm looking for but all the data ends up in one column when writing to a .csv. If it were possible to comma deliminate the data instead of tab, that might solve the issue.

The closes I've gotten is defining two variables: ChildSizes and ChildPaths. With each being only a list of the data I want.

I've tried echo, printf, and now paste without getting exactly what I want and am a bit stumped.

```
set RootDirectoryPosix to POSIX path of RootDirectoryAlias
set ChildSizes to do shell script ("du -sh -- " & RootDirectoryPosix & "*" & "| cut -f1")
set ChildPaths to do shell script ("du -sh -- " & RootDirectoryPosix & "*" & "| cut -f2")
set ChildPathsString to ChildPaths as string
set ChildSizesString to ChildSizes as string
tell application "Finder"
    do shell script "paste -d ," & ChildSizesString & " " & ChildPathsString & " >~/Test.csv"
end tell
```

Comment: Hi
have you tried dumping the raw output data to a file to see what it looks like and it might be a good idea to include that output in your description so others can get a better look at your CSV data file.

I suspect the issue may be that your output has new lines embedded in the variables being used.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I see some of my code got missed the cut when I originally posted. Sorry about that. Nonetheless, I figured it out with Robert's help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Here, I choose for the root folder the Scripts folder from user domain. Following script creates CSV file on the desktop.

As I checked the shell command creates text delimited with **TABs**. The script simply replaces them with **";" delimiter**.

```
set rootFolder to path to scripts folder from user domain
set RootDirectoryPosix to quoted form of (POSIX path of rootFolder)

set csvText to do shell script "du -sh -- " & RootDirectoryPosix & "*"

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, tab}
set csvText to text items of csvText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ";"
set csvText to csvText as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

set fileRef to open for access file (((path to desktop) as text) & "Desktop CSV file .csv") with write permission
write csvText to fileRef as «class utf8»
close access fileRef
```

With adding column titles:

```
set rootFolder to path to scripts folder from user domain
set RootDirectoryPosix to quoted form of (POSIX path of rootFolder)

set csvText to "   The Sizes   ;   The Paths    " & return
set csvText to csvText & (do shell script "du -sh -- " & RootDirectoryPosix & "*")

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, tab}
set csvText to text items of csvText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ";"
set csvText to csvText as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

set fileRef to open for access file (((path to desktop) as text) & "Desktop CSV file .csv") with write permission
write csvText to fileRef as «class utf8»
close access fileRef
```

Comment: Thank you! I tweaked it a little bit to get what I wanted:

Answer (score 0):

This is what I ended up with:

```
set rootFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select directory to run du -sh against
set rootFolder to choose folder with prompt "Select root directory"
set RootDirectoryPosix to quoted form of (POSIX path of rootFolder)

set csvText to "The Sizes,The Paths" & return
set csvText to csvText & (do shell script "du -sh -- " & RootDirectoryPosix & "*")

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, tab}
set csvText to text items of csvText
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set csvText to csvText as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to TID

set fileRef to open for access file (((path to desktop) as text) & "RootFolderdu-sh.csv") with write permission
write csvText to fileRef as «class utf8»
close access fileRef
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).